# Deactivate part of page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a quiz in the style of Buzzfeed. Is there a way to deactivate a part of the page when the user clicks on an answer, so that users can no longer click on alternative options of the same question and thus distort the final score of the test.

I've found some similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371610/jquery-disable-parts-of-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674700/disable-all-page-elements-with-modal-feature-using-jquery) but I don't want to add overlays and I'm not using inputs in my code so I was wondering if there is an alternative route.

[I created a codepen here http://codepen.io/kkoutoup/pen/ByGEoQ](http://codepen.io/kkoutoup/pen/ByGEoQ)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//create an array to store correct answers
var totalCorrect = [];

$('li').click(function(){

    //caching variables
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var $span = $(this).find('.fa');
    //check for .correct class
        //if yes
        if($(this).hasClass('correct')){
            //add .correctAnswer class
            $(this).addClass('correctAnswer');
            //find next span and change icon
            $span.removeClass('fa fa-square-o').addClass('fa fa-check-square-o');
            //reduce opacity of siblings
            $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
            //show answerText
            var $answerReveal= $parent.next('.answerReveal').show();
            var $toShowCorrect = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerC');
            var $toShowFalse = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerF');
            $toShowCorrect.show();
            $toShowFalse.remove();
            //add 1 to total correct array
            totalCorrect+=1;
            //get array's length
            var $finalScore = totalCorrect.length;
            console.log($finalScore);
        }else{
            //add .wrongAnswer class
            $(this).addClass('wrongAnswer').addClass('fade');
            //change icon
            $span.removeClass('fa fa-square-o').addClass('fa fa-check-square-o');
            //reduce opacity of its siblings
            $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
            //show wrong Message
            var $answerReveal= $parent.next('.answerReveal').show();
            var $toShowCorrect = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerC');
            var $toShowFalse = $answerReveal.find('.quizzAnswerF');
            $toShowCorrect.remove();
            $toShowFalse.show();
            //locate correct and add respective class
            $parent.find('.correct').addClass('correctAnswer');

        };
});
});//end dom ready
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So, when any one of the CB's (actually fake CB's) is selected, you'd want to disable the rest for that question no matter what the answer is?

Comment: @LShetty The correct answer is highlighted when the user clicks on any answer, whether right or wrong, so I want to prevent users from being able to click again on any of the <li> for that particular question because if they find the correct answer on the second on third try that would distort the final score of the quizz.

Comment: Right, how about the answers below? Do they help?

Comment: @LShetty Yep, it's working out fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we're doing is removing the `click function` from the `click event` of the selected set of options - in this case, all the `children` of the elements `parent`. Thus when the user tries to `click` again, the `click function` would not be called on the `click event`.

Add the following line in `click function` because we want to trigger the disable as soon as any option is clicked on

```
$(this).parent().find('li').off("click");
```

[Here is the updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbQygw)

Be aware of one thing - `.off('click')` removes all event listeners of type `click` from the element. If you want remove just this function, assign the `function` to a `variable` and then use the `variable` in the `on` and `off` calls. Like below:

```
event_fce = function(event) {
    //do stuff here
    $(this).off('click', event_fce);
}

$('li').on('click', event_fce);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off `click` as soon as one option is selected (right/wrong), like below:

[Codepen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myQgmE)

```
$(this).siblings().off("click"); //add this to where appropriate, such as either in `if` or `else` or both.
```